# Boundary of the boundary of a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove that for a closed set $S$, $S\subset X$ and $(X,d)$ a metric space, $\partial(\partial S)=\partial S$, where $\partial$ is the boundary of S defined as $$\partial S=\{\forall x\in X:\forall \epsilon >0 D(x,\epsilon)\cap S \neq \emptyset \:and\: D(x,\epsilon)\cap S^C = \emptyset\}=cl(S)\cap cl(S^C) $$ where $cl(S)$ is the closure of S.

Here's what I've done so far:
Let $T=\partial S$:

We know that $T$ is closed in X as it is a boundary ([proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Boundary_of_Set_is_Closed)).

I know how to prove that $\partial T \subseteq T$, as since we define a closure of a set as the smallest closed set that contains $T$, thus since $T$ is closed $cl(T)=T$.  We also know that $\partial T \subseteq cl(T)$ and thus $\partial T \subseteq T\implies \partial(\partial S)\subseteq \partial S$.

It's proving that $\partial(\partial S)\supseteq \partial S$ is where I'm having difficulty.

Comment: There's a superfluous "for all $x$" quantifier in your definition of $\partial S$. (I've left it in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial S = \partial (X \setminus S)$ (by definition) and the boundary of an open set is nowhere dense (e.g. [this link](http://planetmath.org/boundaryofaclosedsetisnowheredense)). This means that $\partial S$ (being closed) has no interior points and so $\partial S \subseteq \partial \partial S$ is then easy to see. The other inclusion you already did (basically, the boundary is closed and a set is closed iff it contains its boundary).

Comment: ...for a *closed* set S...

Comment: Sorry - I also failed to notice the word "closed" in the OP, and mistakenly upvoted this answer.  I'll go and stand in the corner.